# Multidimensional records with TArrays, how to set length in Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi

i'm having issues when trying to create the third dimension in a data structure with TArrays.
How can length in the TSensorGroupSeries be set? --> SetLength(fSensorValues, fNbrSensors) in the example below;

I'm trying to create a time series, having sensors, where each sensor provides different measurements (8 values, for example: temp, hum, ...), where the type of measurements are identical at each sensor. The number of sensors changes per location: Minimum 2 sensors, max 16 sensors per location. Measurements are taken every 15 minutes.

regards

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

const
  cSensDiffData = 8;
  cMinSensors   = 2;
  cMaxSensors   = 16;


type
  TSensorValues = record
    fData : Array[0 .. cSensDiffData-1] of Integer;
  end;
  TSensorGroup = record
    fSensorValues : TArray<TSensorValues>;
    class var
      fNbrSensors : Byte;
    constructor Create (NbrSensors : byte);
  end;
  TSensorGroupSeries = record
    fSensorGroup : TArray<TSensorGroup>;
    class var
      fSeriesLength : Integer;
    constructor Create (SeriesLength : Integer; NbrSensors : Byte);
  end;

{ TSensorGroup }

constructor TSensorGroup.Create (NbrSensors: Byte);
begin
  case NbrSensors of
     cMinSensors .. cMaxSensors :
     begin
       fNbrSensors := NbrSensors;
       SetLength(fSensorValues, fNbrSensors);
     end
  else
    raise Exception.Create('Nbr Sensors outside range: ' + NbrSensors.ToString + ' ' + cMinSensors.ToString + ' .. ' + cMaxSensors.ToString);
  end;
end;

var
  i : integer;
  s : string;
  SensorGroup : TSensorGroup;
  SensorGroupSeries : TSensorGroupSeries;

{ TSensorGroupSeries }

constructor TSensorGroupSeries.Create(SeriesLength : Integer; NbrSensors : Byte);
var
  i, j : integer;
  aSensorGroup : TSensorGroup;

begin
  aSensorGroup  := TSensorGroup.Create(NbrSensors);
  fSeriesLength := SeriesLength;
  SetLength(fSensorGroup, fSeriesLength);  // how is the system knowing the real length
end;


begin
// two dimensional data access is working..
  SensorGroup := TSensorGroup.Create(6);
  SensorGroup.fSensorValues[1].fData[2] := 12;
  writeln('Nbr Sensors defined: ' + SensorGroup.fNbrSensors.ToString);
  writeln('value at 0/0: ' + SensorGroup.fSensorValues[0].fData[0].ToString);
  writeln('value at 1/2: ' + SensorGroup.fSensorValues[1].fData[2].ToString);
  writeln('value at max: ' + SensorGroup.fSensorValues[6-1].fData[cSensDiffData-1].ToString);
  readln;
// three dimensional data is causing access error
  SensorGroupSeries := TSensorGroupSeries.Create(100,4);
  SensorGroupSeries.fSensorGroup[5].fSensorValues[2].fData[2]:=5;   // line, where error occurs
  writeln(SensorGroupSeries.fSensorGroup[5].fSensorValues[2].fData[2].ToString);
  readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing ASensorGroup, but not using it. In effect, none of the elements of SensorGroupSeries are initialized and so will all be of zero length.

Here is the corrected constructor:

```
constructor TSensorGroupSeries.Create(SeriesLength : Integer; NbrSensors : Byte);
var
  i : integer;

begin
  fSeriesLength := SeriesLength;
  SetLength(fSensorGroup, fSeriesLength);  // how is the system knowing the real length
  for i := 0 to fSeriesLength - 1 do
  begin
    fSensorGroup[ i ].Create( NbrSensors );
  end;
end;
```

I have tested this and it works.

Comment: If this works for you, please accept the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The three records above can be declared within one to reduce the memory footprint when having 1 Mio sensors:

```
      TSensorGroupSeries = record
//        class var --> do not use class var in this context, to prevent resizing, use private or strict private
          fNbrSensors : Byte;
          fSeriesLength : Integer;
        type
          TSensorGroup = record
            type
              TSensorValues = record
                fData : Array[0 .. cSensDiffData-1] of SmallInt;
              end;
            var
            fSensorValues : TArray<TSensorValues>;
            constructor Create (NbrSensors : byte);
          end;
        var
        fSensorGroup : TArray<TSensorGroup>;
        constructor Create (SeriesLength : Integer; NbrSensors : Byte);
      end;
```

Comment: Class var here looks wrong. Are you clear on what it means?

Comment: No, not really, could you explain it to me? English is not my native language, Switching between the German and English documentation about class fields and the class var doesn't make sense to me. Or, do you have a link? Regards

Comment: The language documentation explains it fine. I can't do better.

Comment: http://forms.embarcadero.com/DownloadMarcoCantueBook

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: thank you, after reading the details, class var should not be used here.

Comment: @Delphi Coder: yes, I found the answer in that book.